# How to allow wordpress to create username with symbols like +

Tags: user-registration, username

I want to allow users to create username with **+** symbol. but wordpess removing the symbol by the register validation process.
If I gave username as **abcd+123**, the user registered with username as **abcd123**.
I need the username registered as it is with **+** symbol.

Answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you might encounter some problems using + in the author urls, since +  is an url encoded version of the space character.

Comment: @birgire No, I just need to change the username as email, So some email can register with + symbol, if so my username too need to contain that + . If any hook like validate_username is there means can re-define.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to add a filter to 'sanitize_user'.

Here is the sample code that will work for you.

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_user', 'tubs_sanitize_user', 10, 3);
function tubs_sanitize_user($username, $raw_username, $strict) {
    $new_username = strip_tags($raw_username);
    // Kill octets
    $new_username = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '', $new_username);
    $new_username = preg_replace('/&.?;/', '', $new_username); // Kill entities

   // If strict, reduce to ASCII for max portability.
   if ( $strict )
        $new_username = preg_replace('|[^a-z0-9 _.\-@+]|i', '', $new_username);

    return $new_username;
}
```

```
Note: This code is the modified version of the original WordPress sanitize_user function.
```

Comment: Me too, just found it :) I need to dig in more